# Clustering points based on their linear proximity

Tags: r, filtering, classification, cluster-analysis, linear-regression

I have data that I want to cluster into two groups based on their linear proximity (i.e., points that are almost collinear gets to be grouped together). Here is a sample of my data:

```
data <- data.frame(Y=c(seq(0,10,1), seq(0,4,0.5)), X= c(0:10,0:8))
plot(jitter(data$Y), jitter(data$X), pch=19)
```

[image]

The result that I want to get is something like this: [image]

Obviously, the regular (`hierarchical` or `K-means`) clustering didn't work. Furthermore, I tried `spectral` clustering also did't provide good result.

Any suggestion on how to do this (using `clustering`, `regression` or other methods) is highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Do you know *a priori* how many clusters you are looking for?

Comment: Yea, I want them to be grouped in to two clusters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the package `mclust`

```
## Add a little noise to the lines
data <- data.frame(Y=c(seq(0,10,1), seq(0,4,0.5))+rnorm(20,0,0.1), X= c(0:10,0:8))

library(mclust)
fit <- Mclust(data)
plot(fit)  # classification
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Transform your data.

Try clustering/analyzing the variable `z = x / y` instead

Comment: Well, the point at 0,0 would belong to both. Any clustering will have difficulty "correctly" assigning them, because it is ambiguous... but clustering methods such as mclust may well decide that e.g. the points close to 0 are one cluster, and the remainder is the second cluster. Run them twice, and you may get very different results. The data transformation approach on the other hand is stable and you can probably find a good theory for it.

Comment: Am gonna try your method as well. Thanks.